# drawImage in background.js not working? Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my **background.js** of my chrome extension I am targeting a canvas HTML tag that exists in my **background.html** file.

However, the method:

```
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
```

is not working. I figured this out by alerting right before and right after. The alert before it triggers, the one after it does not. Is this normal or am I missing something?

Here are my settings:

**Manifest** file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "moodflow",
  "short_name": "moodflow",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0.10",
  "author": "Walter J. Monecke",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "alarms",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/*"
  ]
}
```

My **background.js**:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function() {
    getBackgroundAPI();
});

function getBackgroundAPI() { // AJAX Unsplash API --> compressImageAndSave()
    // background image AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: "client_id=29b43b6caaf7bde2a85ef2cfddfeaf1c1e920133c058394a7f8dad675b99921b&collections=281002",
        success: (response) => {
            alert('successful API');

            $('#source_img').css('display', 'none');

            // insert src into img
            $('#source_img').on('load', function() {
                alert('Image has loaded!');
                compressImageAndSave();
            }).attr('src', response.urls.raw);

            let backgroundInfo = response;
            // save picture information
            chrome.storage.local.set(backgroundInfo, () => {

                return;
            });
        },
            error: () => {

            alert('getPictureApi AJAX failed');
        }
    });
}

function compressImageAndSave() {
    alert('withing compressImageAndSave')
    let source_img = document.getElementById("source_img");
    let compressedSRC;

    //An Integer from 0 to 100
    let quality = 60;
    // output file format (jpg || png)
    let output_format = 'jpg';
    //This function returns an Image Object
    alert('before callin JIC')

    compressedSRC = jic(source_img, quality, output_format).src;

    alert(compressedSRC);

    var savedBackground = {};
    savedBackground.dataURL = compressedSRC;
    alert('right before saving');
    // save to chrome.storage
    chrome.storage.local.set(savedBackground, function() {
        // Notify that we saved.
        alert('compressed dataURL was saved');
    });
} // works in tandem with getBackgroundAPI()

function jic(source_img_obj, quality, output_format) {
    alert('wihtin JIC')
    var mime_type = "image/jpeg";
    if(typeof output_format !== "undefined" && output_format=="png"){
        mime_type = "image/png";
    }
    alert('after if statement');
    var cvs = $('#myCanvas');
    cvs.width = source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
    cvs.height = source_img_obj.naturalHeight;



    alert('before drawing');   //THIS ONE GETS TRIGGERED

    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);

    alert('after drawing');    //THIS ONE NOT




    var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality/100);
    var result_image_obj = new Image();
    result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
    alert('before return');
    return result_image_obj;
}
```

**My background.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="" id="source_img">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

    <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/JIC.js"></script>
    <script src="hot-reload.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is kind of hard for me to debug since I do not have a console available.

Comment: Open chrome://extensions page, enable `developer mode`, inspect your extension's background page in devtools debugger. There should be an error displayed because `$('#myCanvas')` is not a DOM element, but a jQuery wrapper. To access the element you need `$('#myCanvas')[0]`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for always helping me out! The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: cvs.getContext is not a function
    at jic (background.js:128)
    at compressImageAndSave (background.js:103)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (background.js:75)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)` Why doesnt jquery work like in my DOMmanipulation.js?

Comment: on click `background page` you can debug your code. look this image. `http://imgur.com/mE542xs`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you so much! You are great!